# Загрузчик изображений (БЕЗ БЭКЭНДА)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Как на js cоздать интерактивный загрузчик изображений. Выбрать файл изображения/или дропнуть                (показать прогрессбар загрузки в процентах). Изображение появится в поле под цифрой (1), соответственно если будет больше изображений, то под цифрой (1) будет последнее, остальные правее. Предоставить возможность менять изображения (загруженные) местами по средствам drag&drop. Изображения сохранять в браузер. БЕЗ ИСПОЛЬЗОВАНИЯ Backend!

Пример: [image: пример]

Comment: использовать localeStorage?

Comment: можно и его.......

Answer (score 0):

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  const dropArea = document.querySelector('#drop-area');
  const list = document.querySelector('#list');

  const acceptedTypes = ['image/jpeg', 'image/png'];
  const fileReader = new FileReader();
  fileReader.onload = () => {
    const img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = fileReader.result;
    img.style.width = '50px';
    list.appendChild(img);
  };

  dropArea.addEventListener('dragover', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
  })

  dropArea.addEventListener('drop', (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();

    if (!event.dataTransfer || !event.dataTransfer.files || !event.dataTransfer.files.length) {
      return;
    }

    Object.values(event.dataTransfer.files).forEach(file => {
      if (acceptedTypes.indexOf(file.type) === -1) {
        return
      }

      fileReader.readAsDataURL(file)
    })
  })
})
```

```html
<div id="drop-area" style="width: 200px; height: 200px; border: 1px solid #000">
  <p>Перетащите нужные изображения в выделенную область</p>
</div>
<div id="list"></div>
```